# VBA array write to .txt file

Tags: arrays, vba, text-files

I am having problems getting my array to write to a txt.file correctly.
What it does currently, is display the results in a msgbox so we can see it straight away, and writes only some of the data that appeared in that msgbox into the txt.file.

I tried using 'Append' which does display all the data, but of course, it only adds the data to the txt.file rather than replacing what is already in there.
'Output' I think is the only way of getting it to write all the data into the txt.file, and then also replace it each time.

Sadly, I cannot get it to work with 'output'. It currently only writes the last line of data that was in the array.

I assume I need some kind of loop, but I cannot figure out a way to get it to work successfully.

My code is below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Function Expired(ByRef msg As String, ByRef var1 As Variant, ByRef 
var2 As Variant, ByRef var3 As Variant) As String
Dim sFilePath As String


Dim FileNumber


If Len(msg) = 0 Then msg = "Persons with EXPIRED Safeguading 
Certificates:@NL@NL"
Expired = msg & "@var1 @var2 (@var3)@NL"
Expired = Replace(Expired, "@var1", var1)
Expired = Replace(Expired, "@var2", var2)
Expired = Replace(Expired, "@var3", var3)


sFilePath = "R:\HR and Admin\Expired.txt"
FileNumber = FreeFile
If (VBA.Len(VBA.Dir(sFilePath))) = 0 Then MsgBox "File Does not exists": End
Open sFilePath For Output As #FileNumber 
Print #FileNumber , var1, var2, var3


Close #FileNumber
```

The following is all the code for the vba sheet:

```
    Public Sub Expire_New(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByVal Name As String)

Dim msg(1 To 3) As String
Dim x           As Long
Dim nDx         As Long
Dim dDiff       As Long

'Establish the location of the first cell (range) of the Safegaurding Training block
'Find the first instance of Safeguarding Training on the sheet
Dim sgTrainingCol As Range
With ws.Range("A1:AA1000")  'Using something large to provide a range to search
    Set sgTrainingCol = .Find("Safeguarding Training", LookIn:=xlValues)
End With

'Establish the location of the first cell (range) of the heading column
'for the table on the sheet. Find the first instance of what is contained
'in mTitleFirstHeadingColumn
Dim HeadingRangeStart As Range
With ws.Range("A1:AA1000")  'Using something large to provide a range to search
    Set HeadingRangeStart = .Find(Name, LookIn:=xlValues)
End With

Dim TrainingInfoRange As Range
Dim personFNSR As Range
With ws
    'finds the last row of the Heading column that has data, there can NOT be any empty rows
    'in the middle of this search.  It assumes that the name column date is contigous until
    'reaching the end of the data set.
    x = .Cells(HeadingRangeStart.Row, HeadingRangeStart.Column).End(xlDown).Row
    'Set the TrainingInfoRange to point to the data contained in the 4 columns under Safeguarding Training
    Set TrainingInfoRange = .Range(.Cells(sgTrainingCol.Row + 2, sgTrainingCol.Column), .Cells(x, sgTrainingCol.Column + 3))
    'Set pseronFNSR to the First Name/Name, Surname range
    Set personFNSR = .Range(.Cells(HeadingRangeStart.Row + 1, HeadingRangeStart.Column), .Cells(x, HeadingRangeStart.Column + 1))
End With

'I am a big fan of collections and scripting dictionaries.
'They make code easier to read and to implement.
Dim trainingDate As Scripting.Dictionary
Set trainingDate = CopyRngDimToCollection(personFNSR, TrainingInfoRange)

'This boolean will be used to control continued flow of the
'macro.  If NoExpiredTraining gets set to false, then there
'are people who must complete training.
Dim NoExpiredTraining As Boolean: NoExpiredTraining = True

'person training inquiry object - see class definition
Dim personInquiryTraining As clPersonTraining

'this is an index variable used to loop through items
'contained in the Scripting Dictionary object
Dim Key As Variant

For Each Key In trainingDate.Keys
    'Assing the next object in the trainingDate Scripting Dictionary
    'to the person training inquiry object
    Set personInquiryTraining = trainingDate(Key)
    'Check to see if there are any training issues
    'if so, then set NoExpiredTraining to False
    'because there is expired, expiring or missing training
    If personInquiryTraining.ExpiringTraining _
      Or personInquiryTraining.NoTraining _
      Or personInquiryTraining.TrainingExpired Then
        NoExpiredTraining = False
    End If
Next

If NoExpiredTraining Then
    'msg(4) = MsgBox("There are either no ...
    'is only used if want to do something based on
    'what button the user pressed.  Otherwise use
    'the Method form of MsgBox
    MsgBox "There are either no expired safeguarding certificates, " _
         & "or no certificate expiring within the next 31 days.", _
         vbInformation, "Warning"
    Exit Sub
End If

'If this code executes, then there is expired training.
'Let's collect the status for each individual
For Each Key In trainingDate.Keys
    Set personInquiryTraining = trainingDate(Key)
    If personInquiryTraining.TrainingExpired _
      And personInquiryTraining.trainingDate <> DateSerial(1900, 1, 1) Then 'Training is expired
        msg(1) = Expired(msg(1), _
              personInquiryTraining.firstName, _
              personInquiryTraining.surName, _
              personInquiryTraining.trainingExpiryDate)
    End If
    If personInquiryTraining.ExpiringTraining _
      And personInquiryTraining.trainingExpiryDate <> DateSerial(1900, 1, 1) Then 'Training is expiring
        msg(2) = Expiring(msg(2), _
              personInquiryTraining.firstName, _
              personInquiryTraining.surName, _
              personInquiryTraining.trainingExpiryDate, _
              DateDiff("d", Date, personInquiryTraining.trainingExpiryDate))
    End If
    If personInquiryTraining.NoTraining Then 'Training is None
        msg(3) = NoTraining(msg(3), _
              personInquiryTraining.firstName, _
              personInquiryTraining.surName, _
              "NONE")
    End If
Next

'Because of the Exit Sub statement above, the code bwlow
'will only execute if there are expired, expiring or missing
'training
For x = LBound(msg) To UBound(msg)
    msg(x) = Replace(msg(x), "@NL", vbCrLf)
    If Len(msg(x)) < 1024 Then
    Select Case msg(x)
Case msg(1)
    If Len(msg(x)) & vbNullString > 0 Then
        'MsgBox "(If this box is blank, there is nothing Expired)" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & msg(x), vbExclamation, "Safeguarding Certificate Notification"
        MsgBox msg(x), vbCritical, "Safeguarding Certificate Notification"
        End If
Case msg(2)
    If Len(msg(x)) & vbNullString > 0 Then
        'MsgBox "(If this box is blank, there is nothing Expired)" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & msg(x), vbExclamation, "Safeguarding Certificate Notification"
        MsgBox msg(x), vbExclamation, "Safeguarding Certificate Notification"
        End If
Case msg(3)
    If Len(msg(x)) & vbNullString > 0 Then
        'MsgBox "(If this box is blank, there is nothing Expired)" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & msg(x), vbExclamation, "Safeguarding Certificate Notification"
        MsgBox msg(x), vbCritical, "Safeguarding Certificate Notification"
        End If
        End Select
Else
     MsgBox "String length for notification too long to fit into this MessageBox", vbExclamation, "Invalid String Length to Display"
End If

Next x

  End Sub




'***************************************************************************
   '**
    '** This fucntion copies all rows of data for the column specified into
      '** a scripting dictionary
      Private Function CopyRngDimToCollection(ByRef mFNSR As Range, ByRef 
      mTrainInfo) As Scripting.Dictionary

Dim retVal As New Scripting.Dictionary
'nDx will become a key for each of the scripting dictionary items
Dim nDx As Long: nDx = 1
'person training inquiry object - see class definition
Dim personTraining As clPersonTraining

Dim mRow As Range
For Each mRow In mFNSR.Rows
    'instantiate a new person training inquiry object
    Set personTraining = New clPersonTraining
    With personTraining
        .firstName = mRow.Value2(1, 1)
        .surName = mRow.Value2(1, 2)
    End With
    retVal.Add nDx, personTraining
    nDx = nDx + 1
Next
nDx = 1

For Each mRow In mTrainInfo.Rows
    'Retrieve the person training inquiry object
    'from the scripting dictionary (retVal)
    Set personTraining = retVal(nDx)

    'Add the training data information to
    'the person training inquiry object
    With personTraining
        'Next two equations determine if the excel range has a null value
        'if so then the person training inquiry object's date field is set to a
        'default value of 1-1-1900 - this could be any valid date
        'otherwise the value is set to what is in the excel range from the sheet
        .trainingDate = IIf(mRow.Value2(1, 1) = vbNullString, DateSerial(1900, 1, 1), mRow.Value2(1, 1))
        .trainingExpiryDate = IIf(mRow.Value2(1, 2) = vbNullString, DateSerial(1900, 1, 1), mRow.Value2(1, 2))
        .trainingLevel = mRow.Value2(1, 3)
        .certSeenBy = mRow.Value2(1, 4)
    End With
    'Update the object stored at the current key location
    'given by the value of nDx
    Set retVal(nDx) = personTraining
    nDx = nDx + 1
Next

'Set the return value for the function
Set CopyRngDimToCollection = retVal

End Function

   Private Function Expired(ByRef msg As String, ByRef var1 As Variant, 
 ByRef var2 As Variant, ByRef var3 As Variant) As String
 Dim sFilePath As String
 Dim FileNumber


    If Len(msg) = 0 Then msg = "Persons with EXPIRED Safeguading 
   Certificates:@NL@NL"
Expired = msg & "@var1 @var2 (@var3)@NL"
Expired = Replace(Expired, "@var1", var1)
Expired = Replace(Expired, "@var2", var2)
Expired = Replace(Expired, "@var3", var3)

  sFilePath = "R:\HR and Admin\Expired.txt"
  FileNumber = FreeFile
  If (VBA.Len(VBA.Dir(sFilePath))) = 0 Then MsgBox "File Does not exists": 
  End

     Open sFilePath For Output As #FileNumber
     Print #FileNumber, var1, var2, var3

    Close #FileNumber



   End Function

    Private Function Expiring(ByRef msg As String, ByRef var1 As Variant, 
   ByRef var2 
  As Variant, ByRef var3 As Variant, ByRef d As Long) As String
 Dim sFilePath As String
  Dim FileNumber

If Len(msg) = 0 Then msg = "Persons with EXPIRING Safeguarding 
Certificates:@NL@NL"

Expiring = msg & "@var1 @var2 (@var3) (@d days remaining)@NL"
Expiring = Replace(Expiring, "@var1", var1)
Expiring = Replace(Expiring, "@var2", var2)
Expiring = Replace(Expiring, "@var3", var3)
Expiring = Replace(Expiring, "@d", d)

  sFilePath = "R:\HR and Admin\Expiring.txt"
  FileNumber = FreeFile
  If (VBA.Len(VBA.Dir(sFilePath))) = 0 Then MsgBox "File Does not exists": 
  End

 Open sFilePath For Output As #FileNumber
  Print #FileNumber, var1, var2, var3

  Close #FileNumber


  End Function

   Private Function NoTraining(ByRef msg As String, ByRef var1 As Variant, 
   ByRef var2 As Variant, ByRef var3 As Variant) As String
  Dim sFilePath As String
  Dim FileNumber
 If Len(msg) = 0 Then msg = "SAFEGUARDING TRAINING NOT COMPLETED FOR: 
 @NL@NL"

NoTraining = msg & " @var1 @var2@NL"
NoTraining = Replace(NoTraining, "@var1", var1)
NoTraining = Replace(NoTraining, "@var2", var2)
NoTraining = Replace(NoTraining, "@var3", var3)

  sFilePath = "R:\HR and Admin\NoTraining.txt"
  FileNumber = FreeFile
  If (VBA.Len(VBA.Dir(sFilePath))) = 0 Then MsgBox "File Does not exists": 
  End

   Open sFilePath For Output As #FileNumber
   Print #FileNumber, var1, var2, var3

   Close #FileNumber


   End Function
```

Comment: So where is this array that you're referring to? Are you looping over this code from another procedure?

Comment: @Comintern this function is called from my main procedure. It displays data based on the date that is located in the cell.  Var1 is the first name, var2 is the surname, and var3 is the date. Currently we get a msgbox with the right data, I just can't get it to also write it to a .txt file properly. Currently with 'output' it displays just the last line of the array data. 'Append' displays all the right data, but it does not replace the .txt file - only adds to it. It would need to replace and save over the old data in the .txt file.

Comment: In that case, you're blowing away the file every time you call this. You need to open the file *before you start the loop*, not with every iteration. Can you edit the question to include the calling code?

Comment: @Comintern just did. Please check - I am assuming I would just copy the code into the other functions as they are all pretty much the same (would just need to change the odd thing).

Comment: OK, so you have 3 files you're writing to? Open all three before the `For Each` in the calling code, and then pass the appropriate file handle to each function.

Comment: Would you be able to put this into code? I don't think I am quite understanding where to put it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the file *once* instead of looping over the file open. The easiest way to change your existing code is to open all 3 files before you start the loop, and then close them when you're done. Then pass the open file handle to the procedure that writes it:

```
Dim expiredFile As Integer, expiringFile As Integer, notrainingFile As Integer

expiredFile = FreeFile
Open "R:\HR and Admin\Expired.txt" For Output As #expiredFile
expiringFile = FreeFile
Open "R:\HR and Admin\Expiring.txt" For Output As #expiringFile
notrainingFile = FreeFile
Open "R:\HR and Admin\NoTraining.txt" For Output As #notrainingFile

For Each Key In trainingDate.Keys
    Set personInquiryTraining = trainingDate(Key)
    If personInquiryTraining.TrainingExpired _
       And personInquiryTraining.trainingDate <> DateSerial(1900, 1, 1) Then
        'Training is expired
        msg(1) = expired(expiredFile, msg(1), _
                         personInquiryTraining.firstName, _
                         personInquiryTraining.surName, _
                         personInquiryTraining.trainingExpiryDate)
    End If
    '...
Next

Close #expiredFile
Close #expiringFile
Close #notrainingFile
```

Called function example:

```
Private Function expired(FileNumber As Integer, ByRef msg As String, ByRef var1 As Variant, _
                         ByRef var2 As Variant, ByRef var3 As Variant) As String
    expired = msg & "@var1 @var2 (@var3)@NL"
    expired = Replace(expired, "@var1", var1)
    expired = Replace(expired, "@var2", var2)
    expired = Replace(expired, "@var3", var3)
    Print #FileNumber, var1, var2, var3
End Function
```

Note that this is somewhat of a hack to fit your existing code, because you are doing too much in the calling procedure. A much better solution would be to separate the selection logic (your calling loop) from the file output entirely. It would be much more robust if you processed the array first, pushing the results into a `Collection` or some other container, and then had a single "write" function that takes a file name to generically write them to a passed file name.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't quite work - it just says 'expected array', I have now changed the questions to include all the code in my excel sheet in case you can see an easier way to do it.

Comment: @NWally - My bad, the example had the file handle variables named the same as the functions. See the edit.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! I just had to change the # to match the correct one

Comment: @NWally Oops - missed those in the first edit (fixed).

Answer (score -1):

I fixed your code. You missed Semicolon in your `Print` that why it didn't work.

```
Option Explicit

Private Function Expired( _
        ByRef msg As String, _
        ByRef var1 As Variant, _
        ByRef var2 As Variant, _
        ByRef var3 As Variant _
    ) As String

    ' Init Vars
    Dim msg_ As String
    Dim Block As String
    Dim sFilePath As String: sFilePath = "R:\HR and Admin\Expired.txt"
    Dim FileNumber As Integer: FileNumber = FreeFile


    ' Check if msg has no value
    If msg = vbNullString Then msg_ = "Persons with EXPIRED Safeguading Certificates:@NL@NL"

    Block = msg & _
        "@" & var1 & " " & _
        "@" & var2 & " " & _
        "(@" & var3 & ")@NL"

    ' Text File
    If Dir(sFilePath) = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "File Does not exists"

        ' Return nothing
        Expired = vbNullString
    Else
        Open sFilePath For Output As #FileNumber
        Print #FileNumber, var1, var2, var3;
        Close #FileNumber

        ' Return Block
        Expired = Block
    End If

End Function
```

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Debug.Print Expired("f", 1, 2, 3)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I think using this code may change my entire thing. Currently this code is called as a function which displays a msgbox on screen. Changing it to that above I think will remove what it does - it is meant to display the msg on screen, and also write to a txt file. Or does this still do it?

Comment: @NWally I only did here is optimized your code. Your `Expired` (It should be return a value because this is a Function not a Sub) is act like a variable which is absurd. I created a local variable which you can put them all of your variables and use it as return value.

Comment: I tested it, but it does not quite work. It uses append, but it would need to use OUTPUT i think, as I need it to replace the data in the .txt file everytime and not add to it.

Comment: I 'd update the code. I replaced the `Open sFilePath For Append As #FileNumber` into `Open sFilePath For Output As #FileNumber`

Comment: @NWally It will replace the data in the .txt file everytime you call the function.

Comment: I tried that, but it still only displays the last line of the array data. I think there needs to be some kind of loop with OUTPUT.